# select based on whether the value of a property is enclosed by double quotes

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a custom attribute on a specific tag, and I want a selector that will match only if the value of the attribute is enclosed by double quotes. I've found several questions/answers about whether quotes are required around the property, but in my case I will have some values with quotes and some without.

For example, I might have some HTML that contains the following:

```
<p myProperty=12345>some text</p>
<p myProperty="12345">some text</p>
<p myProperty="67890">some text</p>
```

Is there a way to write a selector that will only select the second and third elements? The actual values are irrelevant, I just want the elements where the value of that specific property is enclosed by quotes.

My experimentation and reading so far suggests that when the quotes are present, they are disregarded when matching with something like:

```
a[myProperty*='"'] { ... }
```

but I am hoping someone here might know of a way to do this.

Comment: how about using javascript? css doesn't have regex, and this doesn't seems to be working.

Comment: JS/regex is my backup plan, but I am validating the html with a library that uses CSS-style selectors to flag problems and was hoping to make all the errors come from the same source if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to write a selector that will only select the second and third elements?

No, that's not possible, assuming the location of the quotes is subject to change (i.e. you can't just select your desired elements with `p:nth-of-type(2), p:nth-of-type(3)` because the element with quotes may not always be the first `p`).

In fact, it is completely impossible to distinguish your first and second `p` elements by *any* means (except, again, by their source order), because as far as the DOM is concerned, they are **identical**, both having a `myProperty` attribute with a value of `12345`. The presence of quotes does not change the attribute value, nor how the HTML is parsed and turned into a DOM tree.

If your HTML cannot be changed, and the assumption about the location of the quotes is true, then your only recourse is treating the source as plain text, not HTML, and manually parsing it with a custom parser. As it is currently written, HTML itself does not meet your requirements due to the meaning of attribute value quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your html as follows :

```
<p myProperty='12345'>some text</p>
<p myProperty='"12345"'>some text</p>
<p myProperty='"67890"'>some text</p>
```

**Single quotes have been used to wrap attribute values to allow use of double quotes**

Use the following selector to match only p elements with myProperty attribute value in double quotes.

```
document.querySelectorAll("p[myProperty*='\"']");
```

**" has been modified to \" in the queryselector**

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I am unable to change the html.

Comment: without the changes, myProperty=12345 and myProperty="12345" are both visible as myProperty="12345" if you inspect the DOM using developer tools in any of the browser. The browser is treating all the three elements similarly.